# How do I count the number of instances of particular words in a paragraph?

Tags: ruby, text

I'd like to count the number of times a set of words appear in each paragraph in a text file. I am able to count the number of times a set of words appears in an entire text.

It has been suggested to me that my code is really buggy, so I'll just ask what I would like to do, and if you want, you can look at the code I have at the bottom.

So, given that "frequency_count.txt" has the words "apple pear grape melon kiwi" in it, I want to know how often "apple" shows up in each paragraph of a separate file "test_essay.txt", how often pear shows up, etc., and then for these numbers to be printed out in a series of lines of numbers, each corresponding to a paragraph.

For instance:

```
apple, pear, grape, melon, kiwi
3,5,2,7,8
2,3,1,6,7
5,6,8,2,3
```

Where each line corresponds to one of the paragraphs.

I am very, very new to Ruby, so thank you for your patience.

```
output_file = '/Users/yirenlu/Quora-Personal-Analytics/weka_input6.csv'
o = File.open(output_file, "r+")

common_words = '/Users/yirenlu/Quora-Personal-Analytics/frequency_count.txt'
c = File.open(common_words, "r")

c.each_line{|$line1|
    words1 = $line1.split
    words1.each{|w1|
        the_file = '/Users/yirenlu/Quora-Personal-Analytics/test_essay.txt'
        f = File.open(the_file, "r")
        rows = File.readlines("/Users/yirenlu/Quora-Personal-Analytics/test_essay.txt")
        text = rows.join
        paragraph = text.split(/\n\n/)
        paragraph.each{|p|
            h = Hash.new
            puts "this is each paragraph"
            p.each_line{|line|
                puts "this is each line"
                words = line.split
                words.each{|w|
                    if w1 == w
                        if h.has_key?(w)
                            h[w1] = h[w1] + 1
                        else
                            h[w1] = 1
                        end
                        $x = h[w1]
                    end
                }
            }
            o.print "#{$x},"
        }
    }
    o.print "\n"
    o.print "#{$line1}"
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest that using more descriptive variable names and consistent indenting (especially for blocks) would make the question a lot easier to answer. You might even find the bug yourself !

Comment: You are not "mostly there" at all. I tried to improve your code, but it turns out that the problem is not just about handeling a hash. There are all kinds of mistakes in the code you posted. As Palmer notes, you do not even do consistent indenting, so people will not feel like reading your code. It is easier to throw out your code and ask someone what you want to do.

Comment: OK, then I've given you a fairly complete answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternate answer, which is has been tweaked for conciseness (though not as easy to read as my other answer).

```
require 'csv'

words = %w(apple pear grape melon kiwi)
text = File.open("test_essay.txt").read

CSV.open("file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  text.split(/\n\n/).map {|p| csv << words.map {|w| p.scan(/\b#{w}\b/).length}}
end
```

I prefer the slightly longer but more self-documenting code, but it's fun to see how small it can get.

Answer (score 1):

If you're used to PHP or Perl you may be under the impression that a variable like `$line1` is local, but this is a global. Use of them is highly discouraged and the number of instances where they are strictly required is very short. In most cases you can just omit the `$` and use variables that way with proper scoping.

This example also suffers from nearly unreadable indentation, though perhaps that was an artifact of the cut-and-paste procedure.

Generally what you want for counters is to create a hash with a default of zero, then add to that as required:

```
# Create a hash where the default values for each key is 0
counter = Hash.new(0)

# Add to the counters where required
counter['foo'] += 1
counter['bar'] += 2

puts counter['foo']
# => 1
puts counter['baz']
# => 0
```

You basically have what you need, but everything is all muddled and just needs to be organized better.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two one-liners to calculate frequencies of words in a string.

The first one is a bit easier to understand, but it's less effective:

```
txt.scan(/\w+/).group_by{|word| word.downcase}.map{|k,v| [k, v.size]}
# => [['word1', 1], ['word2', 5], ...]
```

The second solution is:

```
txt.scan(/\w+/).inject(Hash.new(0)) { |hash, w| hash[w.downcase] += 1; hash}
# => {'word1' => 1, 'word2' => 5, ...}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be shorter and easier to read if you use:

1. The CSV library.
2. A more functional approach using map and blocks.

```ruby
require 'csv'

common_words = %w(apple pear grape melon kiwi)
text = File.open("test_essay.txt").read

def word_frequency(words, text)
  words.map { |word| text.scan(/\b#{word}\b/).length }
end

CSV.open("file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  paragraphs = text.split /\n\n/
  paragraphs.each do |para| 
    csv << word_frequency(common_words, para)
  end
end
```

Note this is currently case-sensitive but it's a minor adjustment if you want case-insensitivity.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that there was a csv library. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Would you like to accept this answer then? (and vote up any helpful answers too)

Answer (score 0):

To count how many times one word appears in a text:

```
text = "word aaa word word word bbb ccc ccc"
text.scan(/\w+/).count("word") # => 4
```

To count a set of words:

```
text = "word aaa word word word bbb ccc ccc"
wlist = text.scan(/\w+/)
wset = ["word", "ccc"]
result = {}
wset.each {|word| result[word] = wlist.count(word) }
result # => {"word" => 4, "ccc" => 2}
result["ccc"] # => 2
```

Comment: Are you sure that `result << wlist.count(word)` works? How does `result` get the information about the key?

Comment: @sawa how I left it?? Thank you, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
# Create an array of regexes to be used in `scan' in the loop.
# `\b' makes sure that `barfoobar' does not match `bar' or `foo'.
p word_list = File.open("frequency_count.txt"){|io| io.read.scan(/\w+/)}.map{|w| /\b#{w}\b/}
File.open("test_essay.txt") do |io|
    loop do
        # Add lines to `paragraph' as long as there is a continuous line
        paragraph = ""
        # A `l.chomp.empty?' becomes true at paragraph border
        while l = io.gets and !l.chomp.empty?
            paragraph << l
        end
        p word_list.map{|re| paragraph.scan(re).length}
        # The end of file has been reached when `l == nil'
        break unless l
    end
end
```